# Scaling stroke-width in a <shape> drawable

Tags: android

So I have this happy little shape:

```
<shape android:shape="oval">
    <size android:width="20dp"
          android:height="20dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#FF88EE88"/>
    <stroke android:color="#FFEE8800" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

You can see, that it's quite plump and thick and small and very very cute.

Now when I try to put it as a background of some View, it's `<size/>` gets scaled to the size of that View, but its `<stroke/>` stays the same, which means it's barely noticeable on some 500x500 View.

What is a correct way (if there is any) to make stroke width scale with size in Android?

Comment: you can create separate dimens file for different dpis and put your values in same variable and assign that variable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your shape drawable to a vector drawable:

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF88EE88"
        android:pathData="M1 12a11 11 0 1 1 0 0.0001"/>

    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FFEE8800"
        android:strokeWidth="2"
        android:pathData="M1 12a11 11 0 1 1 0 0.0001"/>

</vector>
```

Now when you use it at any size, it will scale up perfectly at any dpi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_with_stroke"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_with_stroke"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Woah! That is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

As you are using xml file,you have to try-run with different width and height measurement to make it fit as your Background drawable.As the below code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape android:shape="oval"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <size android:width="40dp"
            android:height="40dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#FF88EE88"/>
        <stroke android:color="#FFEE8800" android:width="4dp"/>
    </shape>
```

OR Simplest and easiest way to make .png image of this view.and put it in Background of Some View.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use this library to make text and layout design responsive.

just add this dependency in build.gradle(app level).
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

always prefer to use ssp is for text size, and sdp is for margin, padding and layout size.

after that 2 dimension class will be added to your project.

Hope it resolve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate dimens file for each dpi and use common variable that will have different value based on your dpi.

1. put `dimens.xml` in each of your `values` folder
2. Define a common variable with same name in each dimen and assign suitable value.

   `<dimen name="your_value">2dp</dimen>`
3. use that variable in your shape xml

   `<stroke android:color="#FFEE8800" android:width="@dimen/your_value"/>`